# Talend for Big Data, Neo4j and NullPointerException on tNeo4jOutput

Tags: java, exception, neo4j, etl, talend

I am currently transferring all my data from a RDBMS (Postgres) to Neo4j 1.9.6 using Talend Open Studio for Big Data. I have built a Job that runs perfectly within the Talend interface. But then when I build and export the job script (jar with the executable bash script), the program fails to run. Upon running, it throws the following exception:

> Exception in component tNeo4jOutput_2
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>      at postgres.tPostgresqlInput_1Process(postgres.java:2049)
>      at postgres.tPostgresqlConnection_1Process(postgres.java:619)
>      at postgres.runJobInTOS(postgres.java:5871)
>      at postgres.main(postgres.java:5760)

I tried to debug the generated script and imported it along with the libraries to Netbeans 8.0. Here is the culprit:

```
    indexNodeMap_tNeo4jOutput_2.put("label_idx",
    databaseService_tNeo4jOutput_2.index().forNodes("label_idx"));
```

It does not matter if I comment out this piece of code, because then the program crashes on the next reference to tNeo4jOutput2.

Any idea what is going wrong? And why does it work perfectly from within Talend Open Studio?